# How to interpret the asterisks in this line of C code?

Tags: c

```
  *(int *)CV = (int)0;
```

I was looking at a C code and can't understand this line of code. Could you interpret this and explain what it does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It casts `CV` to a pointer to an `int`, dereferences said pointer, and assigns the pointed-to `int` the value `0`.

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/xwhQIVlc) Also, `(int)0` is the same as `0` in this situation, so that can be changed to make things a little simpler.

Answer (score 3):

It first casts `CV` into an int pointer then sets the integer pointed to by it to zero.

The casting of the `0` is not actually necessary.

You often see it in situations like:

```
void setIntWithVoidPtr (void *p) {
    *((int*)p) = 42;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They're casting the variable `CV` to the type `int *` (a pointer to an int), then dereferencing it, with the outer `*`, and assigning to that the value `0` casted to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `CV` is a `void *` which is first casted to `int *`, then dereferenced and the value is set to 0. `int` in `(int)0` though, seems unnecessary.